# SQL Can't create Foreign key

Tags: sql

I'm sure my question would be kinda silly, but I can't solve it. Here is my issue:

```
create table Product
(
    ProductID int PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductName varchar(16),
    RetrailPrice int,
    WholesalePrice int,
    MonthDelivery int,
    Waste int,
    StorageName varchar(16)
)

create table Storage
(
    StorageID int PRIMARY KEY,
    StorageName varchar(16),
    City varchar(16),
    Employees int,
    Area int,
    ProductID int
)
```

And of course I want to link them

```
alter table Product
    add FOREIGN KEY (StorageName) references Storage(StorageName)
```

But I can't do it, I'm wrong somewhere :/

Comment: You don't reference a primary key, just a plain column.

Comment: You forgot to say the database engine. Also, is `Can't create Foreign key` the actual complete unabridged error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reference the PK from the Storage table. StorageName is a poor choice for a FK. What if there are Storages with the same name in different cities?

Replace the StorageName in the Product table with StorageID

```
create table Product(
ProductID int PRIMARY KEY,
ProductName varchar(16),
RetrailPrice int,
WholesalePrice int,
MonthDelivery int,
Waste int,
StorageID int)   --this has chnaged, it will hold the id/PK of the Storage

create table Storage(
StorageID int PRIMARY KEY,
StorageName varchar(16),
City varchar(16),
Employees int,
Area int,
ProductID int)
```

And then:

```
alter table Product
add FOREIGN KEY (StorageID) references Storage(StorageID)
```